# Google Drive Share Dialog not working in Windows 10

Tags: google-drive-api, windows-10, microsoft-edge

I have an app set up which launches the Google Drive Share Dialog using the Google Drive SDK [https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/web/share-button].

I am using the below code.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://apis.google.com/js/api.js">
init = function() {
    s = new gapi.drive.share.ShareClient();
    s.setOAuthToken(OAuth-token);
    s.setItemIds(["0Bwe7TJA4cwoaeTVFZTZnQ1NaQXc"]);
    s.showSettingsDialog();
}
window.onload = function() {
    gapi.load('drive-share', init);
}
</script>
```

The issue is that when I try to launch the share dialog in IE browser [version 11] of Windows 10, the sharing system malfunctions. A blank modal with a loading message pops up, and after a few seconds, I receive the following error message:

> Sorry, sharing is unavailable at this time. Please try again later.

There is no message regarding this in the development console also. I checked this in different browsers and this issue does not occur in Chrome or Firefox or in IE version 11 of Windows 7.

My guess is that this has something to do with the iframe rendering in Windows 10 but I'm not sure what to do about it.

Comment: Try to open an [issue here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new).